# best algebra ebook for self-study

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, self-learning

I did a search and found some book recommendations for different kinds of algebra. My situation is that I'm an adult, got into programming well after my college years and want to go to the next level.

I want to work out of the SICP book and the Art of Computer Programming, and I figure that if I can get through a good algebra, then pre-calc textbook that will give me a basic foundation to get started. So, what books would you reccomend? I would like an eBook with lots of exercises that allow me to check my work.

Also, as a side question...what do you all think of some the Algebra for Dummies, Algebra Demystified, and other quick study books. I've been working through the latter, but I'm wondering if it makes sense to get a more thorough, traditional type text book. (these are usually $80 or so as eBooks)

anyway, 
thanks!

Comment: Check out http://mathbuntu.org (there is a link to free books). Down there one of the book is by Dr. Gilbert Strang from MIT (there are other good books too in that list)

Comment: Here are freely available algebra and pre-calc books: http://msenux.redwoods.edu/IntAlgText/ http://www.math.washington.edu/~m120/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://mathbuntu.org (there is a link to free books). Down there one of the book is by Dr. Gilbert Strang from MIT (there are other good books too in that list)